# If i create an instance of a class within invokeLater, are all methods within that class run on the EDT?

Tags: java, multithreading, user-interface, event-dispatch-thread

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Mainwindow frame = new MainWindow();
            frame.setVisible(true);
            }

public class MainWindow extends JFrame {

public MainWindow(){
 // methods to set title, bounds, JPanels, etc.
 }

public static void methodOne(){
// updates GUI
}

public static void methodTwo(){
// also updates GUI
}
```

Question 1: Say I call

```
 MainWindow.methodOne
```

from inside static main, or from another class instantiated in static main.

is methodOne() run from EDT or Initial Thread?

Qustion 2: referring to the code at the top, inside the method

```
@Override
public void run(){
}
```

is it best practice to use:

```
MainWindow frame = new MainWindow();
frame.setVisibility(true);
```

or simply:

```
new MainWindow();
```

and have

```
setVisibility(true)
```

inside the MainWindow constructor, considering that all the methods inside MainWindow are static?

please dumb all answers down, i'm very new to coding....

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Querstion 1**

The code in the methods will run on the thread they are called from, doesn't matter on which thread the object that you're calling the method of was created on. When you create an object on a specific thread, only its constructor is guaranteed to run on that thread.

Also, in this case, since you have `static` methods, those methods don't belong to the `frame` instance, they belong to the `MainWindow` class.

**Question 2**

What method you use depends on what you're trying to do.
The first approach gives you more control, using that, you could create a new instance of the class at some point and show it later.

The second approach is usually used for the main frame, the frame that you show when the program starts you can put that statement in the class' constructor.

Comment: So if my understanding is correct, ActionListeners are run on the EDT, so if an ActionListener calls a static method in another class (lets call this method:  exampleMethod() ), and exampleMethod() calls methodOne() in MainWindow, methodOne() will run on the EDT, however, if static main calls the exampleMethod() and exampleMethod() calls methodOne(), methodOne() will not run on the EDT. Is that correct?

Comment: @DanielMastrorillo Yes, that is correct. The action listeners are called by the system and they are always called on the EDT.  Also, you can use `SwingUtilities.isEventDispatchThread()` to check if you're on EDT.